# Update GRIDView onchange dropdown outside the grid Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, onchange, pjax

is there anyway that we can update gridview from outside dropdown onchange function?
Im using Pjax also..

Example : when we want to load all salesorder of relevant customer.
when select customer from dropdown, need to change gridview.
this is Yii2.

this the view dropdown

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'customer_id')->dropDownList(
                                ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Mcustomer::find()->all(), 'idCustomer', 'C_fnam'),
                                ['prompt'=>'Select...','class'=>'combobox form-control ','name'=>'cusid','onchange'=>'loadcustomerdata()']) ?>
```

and JS Function

```
function loadcustomerdata(){
      var selected = $('#sinvoicepayment-customer_id').val();
     $.ajax({
                            url: '<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl("sinvoicepayment/searchcustomerdata"); ?>',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {'selected':selected},
                            datatype: 'json',
                            success: function(result) {
                               $.pjax.reload({container:"#receipts"});
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                //alert("There may a error on uploading. Try again later");
                            },
                        });

                        return false;*/

    }
```

Controller Function

```
public function actionSearchcustomerdata(){
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post('selected');
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $customer = Mcustomer::find()->where(['idCustomer'=>$post])->one();

        $invoice = Sinvoice::find()->where(['id_customer'=>$post])->one();
        return  ['add'=>$customer->C_address,'contact'=>$customer->C_tel];
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?, Show some of your code what you have tired so far.

Comment: i called onchange function in dropdown .passed data to controller function via ajax.and i can update the gridview, if controller returns the result like this.$.pjax.reload({container:"#receipts"});. but problem is i dont know how to change searchmodel and dataprovider..at the moment im doing same process using "Go" button.

Comment: Show your view and controller code

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: What is the value of `selected`? Did you forget to put the id `sinvoicepayment-customer_id` to the dropdown?